# Why is my score being capped at 194 (not 200) today?

Tags: bug, reputation

[https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/885/jdługosz?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2016-11-23%2022:56:03Z](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/885/jd%C5%82ugosz?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2016-11-23%2022:56:03Z)

I see recent votes having no points, but the day’s score is 194, not 200. What’s up?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, good question.  I *think* it has to do with the deletion of [this post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/61182/can-you-help-me-build-a-hollow-world/61190#61190), from which you had gained 6 reputation.  When it was deleted you lost those 6 points again, but it seems like you've been "charged" for the gain but not refunded the loss.  It's possible that this will be adjusted in a few hours; there are some nightly "fix anomalies" scripts that run.  If it doesn't get fixed on its own by tomorrow, we should retag this [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) to get help from SE.